# Google apps script map api for distance calculation between two points

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

I know there is an api to calculate the distance between two points for google apps but what i am looking for is the google apps script api to calculate the driving distance not the direct distance between two points. Is there such an api?

Answer (score 2):

Google directions API gives you the total distance between the source and destination.
try this

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=nj&destination=ny&sensor=false
```

API Documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions)

Answer (score 0):

One can follow the below link to get more details about it.
  [Calculating driving distance with google map api v2](http://tajendrasengar.blogspot.com/2011/09/distance-between-two-locations-with.html)